# Who and whom problem

Tags: pronouns, whom, who

I learned the rule recently. Then I was confused a little bit.
The song *Every lie*, by My Darkest Days, has the line:

> Trying to undo the love that I'm tied to. **Who haven't you lied to**?

as far as I understand instead of 'who' must be 'whom' or maybe I misunderstood something... or may it be an exception?

Comment: 'Possible duplicate?' write when you are sure, Edwin Ashworth

Comment: Duplicate of  'What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?' and -1 for essentially challenging ELU protocol. This is the set format, not my preferred format.

Answer (score 2):

For those people who use *whom*, that question would indeed be *Whom haven't you lied to?*

Many English speakers today do not use *whom* at all. Many more only use it in very formal circumstances. Few people would use it in a song lyric.

Comment: *"For those people who use whom, that question would indeed be Whom haven't you lied to? [but]

Many English speakers today do not use whom at all. "* __ excellent answer in a nutshell for *anybody* who is wondering about who & whom!

Comment: Most people who use 'whom' would actually say "To whom have you not lied?" Which is awfully formal, pedantic and irritating to many but has the benefit of being reasonably elegant.

Comment: Well, I suppose some would, if they believed the old lie about there being something wrong with ending a sentence with a preposition. You clearly have a different idea of "elegant" from me.

Answer (score 0):

The use of who and whom in standard English depends on the case; if it is in the nominative, which is the case the word "I" is in, then you would use "who" as in *"Who is going to the party?"*.
If the case is dative/accusative (**usually** corresponding to "me", but not always in nonstandard English) then you use "whom" as in *"with whom are you going to the party?"*
You use "whom" after all prepositions and when it is the object or indirect object of a sentence.
That said, the difference between who/whom is declining in use and you can get away with saying "who" whenever you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going by the rules of English that you have learned, then the song lyric is wrong.

It is like saying that "**There's** many problems with that." It's said by people all the time even though, grammatically, it should be "**There are** many problems with that."

It's good that you want to identify what's technically correct—and also how people go against that. (Although if enough people do the *wrong* thing, it will eventually no longer be wrong.) However, at present, no grammar text in the world will tell you that this lyric is right.

Either this lyric was used mistakenly, or it was used deliberately, with full knowledge of grammar versus culture.

---

A quick way of remembering it is to remember that **whom** pairs with **him** (and **who** pairs with **he**).

Correct:

> **Whom** haven't you lied to?
>   You haven't lied to **him**."

Incorrect:

> **Who** haven't you lied to?
>   You haven't lied to **he**."

Correct:

> **Who** said they were going to the party tonight?
>   **He** did.

Incorrect:

> **Whom** said they were going to the party tonight?
>   **Him** did.

Of course, this only gives you the *form*. If it's a woman, then the answer is **her** or **she**. But, only **whom** and **him** share the *m* in common.

So, consider the form of the question and answer. Either it will be **whom** and **him** or it will be **who** and **he**. And only one of those pairings will make sense.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "wrong" lyric, it's words set to music, it is "art". Besides, everyone, nearly, asks "Who did you see yesterday?" Instead of "whom".

Comment: It is not "wrong". It is in everyday modern English, such as many English speakers speak.